# First revision has dup user signature

Tags: bug, design

Eg https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5564429/1 is both the answerer and the revision owner, which are the same. This looks weird.

> [image: Redundancy is redundant!]

The second one also looks kinda long… <sup>([in fact it looks like padding is borked too on MSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlU2j.png))</sup>

Comment: @bluet Yeah, just like how the signature isn't shown on a question page when OP edited. http://i.stack.imgur.com/qIOYh.png

Comment: I'm tempted to ask: How many people view the page? What is the true reach of this? It's no more than slightly weird, and no more than handful of people ever open any particular revision.

Comment: I posted a separate bug report about those width/padding issues: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250407/user-signature-cards-on-old-revisions-look-funny