# User signature cards on old revisions look funny

Tags: bug, design, revisions-list, user-card

[This meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249752/first-revision-has-dup-user-signature), while mainly about something else, also points out that user signatures on old revisions look kind of weirdly stretched out on SO:

> [image: Screenshot]

Also, they seem to be missing padding here on Meta.SE:

> [image: Screenshot]

I figured I'd split this into a separate bug report, so that I can have something to point to when I fix this in [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch). ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The SO width issue is caused by the fact that the style sheet there stretches *all* tables on history pages to 100% width (`#revisions table { width: 100% }`), but the table cell making up the empty space next to the signature still has an inline style of `width: 475px`, which only makes sense for a much narrower table.  Thus, *something* has to give, and Firefox at least ends up stretching the user card cell.

This could be solved either by removing the inline width:

```css
#revisions table.postcell td:first-child[style="width:475px;"] { width: auto !important }
```

<sup>(Of course, it would be much easier to just remove it directly from the HTML code.)</sup>

or by letting the table adopt its natural width, as is done on other SE sites:

```css
#revisions table.postcell { width: auto }
```

---

As for the MSE padding issue, the problem is simply that the CSS rule that inserts padding to user cards only applies on question pages:

```css
.question-page .post-signature .user-info {
    height: 58px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    padding: 3px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: medium none;
}
```

<sup>(Honestly, I'm also pretty sure that most of those properties have *absolutely no visible effect*.  I mean, `border-radius` with no border and a transparent background?  Really?)</sup>

Anyway, the fix is simply to add a new CSS rule that adds some padding to user cards on *all* pages:

```css
.post-signature .user-info { padding: 3px }
```

Comment: The padding issue on Meta seems to have been fixed, but the other issue still persists.